# Android Alarm Manager and receiver is not working in API 17 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Well, this is interesting. My alarm does work properly in other android versions such as API 19, 20, 23 but doesn't work in API 17. I tried many different ways but it is not working on any emulator using API 17.

Here is a sample code. It's a basic alarm which shows a toast message every 10 seconds. It works correctly on the other versions. (Since alarms are not shorter than 60 seconds in versions later than Android 5.1, messages are shown each minute instead of 10 seconds on devices using API 22 and 23, as expected) However, messages are not shown on emulators using API 17. Even onReceive() method of BroadcastReceiver is not being called.

Here is the code:

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sezai.basicalarm">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Alarm"/>
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":my_service" >
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Service:**

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        Log.i("Service:", "Alarm set!");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        // Put here YOUR code.
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
        Log.i("Alarm", "Showed the toast!");
        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }
```

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(mIntent);

        final Context context = this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I tried different emulators such as Nexus 4, Nexus 7, Galaxy Nexus. Each time, when using API 17, the code didn't work. It worked properly on emulators using different APIs.

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 on win7 pro. All components such as AVD Manager, SDK Manager are up to date.

So, is it just me or is it a buglike thing?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Same issue for me also, did you get any solutions for this?